# merging outputs from a loop

Tags: r, loops, merge

I have two datasets and named E and eF respectively.

```
E<- structure(list(Inception_Date = structure(c(962323200, 962323200, 
810950400, 988675200, 1042502400, 1536624000), tzone = "UTC", class =  
c("POSIXct","POSIXt")), Name = c("Calvert Social Index B", "Calvert US   
Large Cap Core Rspnb Idx A", "Green Century Equity Individual 
Investor", "Praxis Value Index A", "Vanguard FTSE Social Index I", 
"Amundi IS Amundi MSCI USA SRI ETF DR")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

eF <- structure(list(Inception_Date = structure(c(760233600, 519868800, 
1380067200, 1101772800, 1325203200, 628473600, 1325203200, 1123804800
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Name = c("Amana     
Growth Investor", "Amana Income Investor", "Amana Income   
Institutional", "American Century Sustainable Equity A", 
"Ariel Appreciation Institutional", "Ariel Appreciation Investor", 
"Ariel Focus Institutional", "Baywood Socially Responsible Invs"
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I applied the following codes to the data E and eF.

```
for (k in 1:nrow(E)) {
F_temp <- eF;
G_temp <- F_temp %>% filter(abs(F_temp$Inception_Date-    
E$Inception_Date[k]) <= 1500);
print(G_temp)}
```

As the "G_temp" under the "Global Environment" shows it as 0 obs. of 2 variables only (which must be the last components in the loop's list), how to make a .csv file that shows all the "G_temp" components merged together removing duplicates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your exact filter criteria would this do it?

```
G_temp <- data.frame(Inception_Date = as.POSIXct(character()),
                     Name = character())
for (k in 1:nrow(E)) {
  G_temp_int <- eF %>%
    filter(abs(eF$Inception_Date - E$Inception_Date[k]) <= 1500)
  G_temp <- bind_rows(G_temp, G_temp_int)
}

G_temp <- G_temp %>%
  distinct(Inception_Date, Name)
write.csv(G_temp, "G_temp.csv")
```